# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aaa"].ConnectionString replace 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Tags: c#, mysql, mono, app-config

I have a winforms app who run on Linux with Mono and I want to take `ConnectionString` from my `app.config` file with

`string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aaa"].ConnectionString`

but it transform `SERVER=127.0.0.1` to `SERVER=localhost` and with this connection string I can't connect to my Mysql DB because:

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially
>   [MySQL DOC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html)

How can I take my connection string and have `SERVER=127.0.0.1`

Comment: `cs = cs.Replace("SERVER=localhost", "SERVER=127.0.0.1");`?

Comment: _"but it transform[s] `SERVER=127.0.0.1` to `SERVER=localhost`"_ - no, it doesn't. Check your configuration file.

Comment: Don't want a replace if I have connection string in app.config it's for have it in one place if I want to change it..
The transformation is not in my app.config but my when I take it from app.config the string I have is "SERVER=localhost" while "SEVER=127.0.0.1" in my app.config

Answer (score 0):

The documentation that you quoted only applies to the `mysql` program, not to Connector/NET (the C# connection library).

According to [its documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html), you must set `ConnectionProtocol=unix` in your connection string to use a Unix socket; otherwise the default is a TCP connection (even to `localhost`).

Thus, replacing the hostname in your connection string is unnecessary.